# Flutter Error: Running Gradle cannot find JAR

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

I have a Flutter App, when i tried to run, the next error appears and immediately stopped

[image]

Comment: Did you refer to this link?
https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/129

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the *.gradle* file in your `C:\Users\Alexis\` directory and then run the project again.

It is going to take a long time downloading the required gradle versions. This will probably work.